# Sender verify failed

Tags: centos, exim

I've got VPS server based on CentOS with DirectAdmin on it. Some of emails sending to me are bounced with message `<receiver@example1.com>: 550 Verification failed for <sender@example2.com> \r\n Sender verify failed`.

What can I do to allow this messages come to my email?

Some exim logs:

```
2017-09-30 07:47:45 H=somecloudserver.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] sender verify fail for <sender@example2.com>: 
2017-09-30 07:47:45 H=somecloudserver.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=no F=<sender@example2.com> rejected RCPT <receiver@example1.com>: Sender verify failed
2017-09-30 07:47:45 H=somecloudserver.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] incomplete transaction (QUIT) from <sender@example2.com>
```

Comment: Impossible to say without actual domains and configuration.

Comment: receiver@example1.com is *@zencore.pl and sender@example2.com is *@gardo.com.pl

Comment: also, I am using default Exim version 4.89 configuration, nothing has been changed changed since installation

Comment: Is your VPS listed in the SPF record?

Answer (score 1):

"Sender verification" checks for a return path for an email address, meaning you must have an A or MX record for example2.com.

[exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_toc.html#TOC804)